# Measurable set in real numbers with arbitrary lebesgue density at some point

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm not sure if this is easy or not, but i can't see the solution (or that it is wrong!)

Suppose that $\alpha \in (0,1)$ is given, Can you find a Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$, such that at point $0$, it has Lebesgue density $\alpha$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let $\alpha _n =\alpha \cdot(\frac 1 n -\frac 1 {n+1})$ and choose a subset $E_n$ of $ (\frac 1 {n+1},\frac 1 n) \cup (-\frac 1 n,-\frac 1 {n+1})$ whose measure is $2\cdot\alpha _n$. Let E be the union of the sets $E_n$. Then E has density $\alpha$.\

Comment: I think it should be “whose measure is $2\alpha_n$”, or else $\alpha_n$ needs to be twice as big

Comment: I think I am right. we only need $\alpha <2$ to be able to choose such a set $E_n$

Answer (score 0):

Here’s full justification for the answer provided by Kavi: 
Suppose first that $t=\frac 1 n$, then $$|(-t,t)|=2\cdot(\sum \alpha\cdot(\frac 1 n-\frac{1}{n+1}))=2\alpha t,$$ hence $\frac{|E\cap (-t,t)|}{2t}=\alpha.$
Now suppose we’re given arbitrary $t\in (\frac 1 n,\frac{1}{n+1})$. Indeed,
$$\frac{2\cdot (\frac{1}{n+1})\alpha}{2\cdot \frac{1}{n}}\leq \frac{|E\cap (-t,t)|}{2t} \leq \frac{2\cdot (\frac{1}{n})\alpha}{2\cdot \frac{1}{n+1}}. $$
And we’re done.